# Windows RAM OID value?

Tags: snmp

Currently looking for the OID(s) to query for:

```
totalRam
freeRam
usedRam
```

'1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0' isn't giving me what I want, and generally I can't find the correct OIDs.

The OIDs are queried through `net-snmp` from npm (node development), but if it works with `snmpwalk`/`snmpget`, it should work fine in the npm.

Answer (score 0):

It might make sense to try [1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1).

I believe if you look at 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.3, one of the types reported is Virtual or Physical memory.

Comment: Unfortunately the snmpwalk at this address returns NoSuchName: 1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1